# Intellij IDEA packs my source code into .apk

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, apk

My project is a Flash pure Actionscript application for Android.
When I build an .apk through Build->Package AIR Application... I get .apk that works okay when installed on an Android device. But when I unzipped the .apk file I noticed that inside it in the "assets" folder is my entire source code which is in the project's folder marked as "Sources Root". How do I prevent this?

Comment: Please check the `Files and folders to package` [setting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/android-tab.html).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control what files will appear in the apk using the `Files and folders to package` [Flash build configuration settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/android-tab.html).